# Reversing of sphere mapping function.

Tags: functions, spheres

I have a function which maps a 3d unit vector $(x,y,z)$ to a 2d vector $(u,v)$ of the form:

\begin{align}
u &= \frac{ x }{ 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (1+z)^2 }} + \frac12 \\
v &= \frac{ y }{ 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (1+z)^2} } + \frac12
\end{align}

There is an implicit 3rd function of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ due to the unit length requirement, of course. Also there is a singularity at $(0,0,-1)$, but for all other $(x,y,z)$ there is a one-to-one mapping between both spaces.

All I want to do is the reverse this function to compute $(x,y,z)$ from a given $(u,v)$ vector. Unfortunately I haven't succeeded doing it so far.

Can anybody help me out with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the identity in a simple different way (without considering the trivial traslation) 
For every $(x,y,z)\in S^2$ your map is

$u=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{z+1}}$

$v= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{y}{\sqrt{z+1}}$

So you have that

$x= 2\sqrt{2} u \sqrt{z+1}$

$y= 2\sqrt{2} v \sqrt{z+1}$

You can calcolate z(u,v) by the identity

$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

So

$8u^2(z+1)+8v^2(z+1)+z^2=1$

and you have that

$z^2+8|(u,v)|^2z +8|(u,v)|^2-1=0$

$z_{12}=-4 |(u,v)|^2+/-\sqrt{16 |(u,v)|^4-8|(u,v)|^2+1}=$

$=-4|(u,v)|^2+/-(4|(u,v)|^2-1)$

So the inverse map is

$x= 2\sqrt{2} u \sqrt{-8|(u,v)|^2+2}$

$y=2\sqrt{2} v \sqrt{ -8|(u,v)|^2+2}$

$z= -8|(u,v)|^2+1$